# Next.js: Issue with Changing Active Link Color After Implementing Multiple Root Layouts

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks

I am currently developing an application using Next.js and using multiple root layouts from the official Next.js documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts). because I needed to style each route individually.

However, after implementing multiple root layouts, I've encountered an issue where the color of the active link is not changing as expected, even though it was working perfectly before changes.

Sorry as I am a beginner, and there is not a lot of information about next.js latest versions

Here's the relevant piece of code where I handle the active link color:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const Sidebar = () => {
    const [isMobileMenuVisible, setIsMobileMenuVisible] = useState(false);
    const pathname = usePathname();

    const isActive = (href) => {
        if (pathname.startsWith(href)) {
            return "text-[#909090]";
        }
        return "";
    };

    const toggleMobileMenu = () => {
        setIsMobileMenuVisible(!isMobileMenuVisible);
    };

    return (
         DACHI-GIORGI GARUCHAVA
         {/* Mobile dropdown menu */}
         <button
            className="text-[#484848] no-underline cursor-pointer font-MPlus1 leading-6 font-thin tracking-wider mb-2"
            onClick={toggleMobileMenu}
            Menu
            {isMobileMenuVisible && (
                The Witness
               {/* Add other links here */}
            )}
           {/* Desktop link list */}
           Invasive Modification
           {/* Add other links here */}
       );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

The

isActive
function checks the

pathname
to determine if the link is active and applies a specific text color accordingly. This logic worked fine before I started using multiple root layouts, which I need to style routes individually.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: please add the codes inside code block with proper padding. If possible, Can you create a running https://codesandbox.io/ demo of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/anukitsim/dachi-next-test/main?workspaceId=6298f2b9-610e-4dd0-8de9-594de7036009

https://4cd4dd-3000.csb.app/

git repository: https://github.com/anukitsim/dachi-next-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ran the GitHub repo you shared in a codesandbox and it looks like the problem isn't related to root layouts. Your `isActive` method is working as expected, and it's adding the `text-[#909090]` class name to your markup as well.

The main problem here is that you created a custom class called `project_link` using the `@apply` directive and the color you specified in that class is actually overriding the color added via `text-[#909090]`, here is a screenshot of the markup for reference:

[image: text-[#909090] getting overridden by the color project_link class]

So the best way to fix this problem is to not use the class abstraction you added with `project_link` and apply the classes inline directly with conditionally applying the color based on whether the link is active or not, because creating abstractions like these defeats the purpose of using tailwind. They even have a section in their docs on why you should avoid [premature class abstractions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#avoiding-premature-abstraction) like these.

If you want to avoid duplication its better if you create a separate component for these links and use that instead, that gets `isActive` passed as a prop from the parent component. In that component you can then apply the class like this:

```
  ...
  className={`no-underline cursor-pointer font-MPlus1 leading-6 font-thin tracking-wider ${isActive ? 'text-[#909090]' : 'text-[#484848]'}`}
  ...
```